# bigcommerce simple ETL authentication

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm working with a Point of Sale computer that is exporting a CSV file. I want to parse that file of inventory items. I want to download the product (search by SKU), update it with whatever is in the Point of Sale system, then send the updated product back to BigCommerce's API.

It seems like the whole API framework is designed around "apps" that end up in their appstore, of which this isn't the case at all.

I want to install a small .exe on a retail Point of Sale system that does an API call, not turn it into a web server and have to put SSL on it.

**Is there a more straight forward way to work with the BigCommerce API then their "app store" route?**

More digging around, I came back to this. So you really can't have any code running that isn't on a publicly available web server, even when you're developing? That can't be right.

> To integrate with our single sign-on flow, your app must be a publicly
>   accessible web application. Choose your preferred language, framework
>   and hosting solution, and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to set up an "app" using OAuth and an SSL certificate for your code you can use the Basic Authentication method for now. Note that this is deprecated and I do not know when exactly they will discontinue this method of authentication. If not wanting to go with SSL and an app at this point that is your best option.
Otherwise you can look at a self-signed SSL certificate if the app is just for your own code but this would again require setting up an app.

Comment: Scott thanks a ton for the help yesterday digging around on this one!

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar situation as yours. You can implement a oauth2 callback by setting up a SSL site on your machine using a self signed cert, say on port 8000. Then, while using the store owner creds 'install' your app from the my apps dashboard to obtain your token.

This is all assuming you've setup a page to handle the callback request and exchange the temporary token for your permanent one.

It's a bit painful starting out but once you get going its not so bad. I did everything in .NET.

Based on my discussion with their API team I wouldn't waste time with basic authentication if you're just starting out since you'll have to convert sooner than later anyways.

You definitely don't need a public SSL callback URL though if you aren't looking to create an app for their marketplace.

Hope this is of some help.